# Popup should display on top of element if no proper space in bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display the popup on the top of element if there is no proper space on the top. Currently it hides inside the window as seen in the image below:
[image: Popup Hide]

I can update the top position but I only want when there is no proper space otherwise it is ok.

Please let me know how to determine if the clicked position in near window edges.

JSFiddle Link :http://jsfiddle.net/g4g4negf/

Code I am using to get the position:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.clickme').on('click', function(e) { 
       $('#popup').offset({ top: e.pageY, left:  e.pageX}).fadeIn(); 
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: @ManojKadolkar Check the fiddle and scroll the second textbox near bottom of window and click on it. Popup will open but most of the portion is hidden because there is no room for that. I want in such situation it should open on the top of the textbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/westlife_8/gykqLbvk/7/)

To check if clicked position is near window edge, you have to get window's height (`$(window).height()`) and scroll position (`window.pageYOffset`). By adding these two values, you can find the scrolled position of the window. Then compare this sum with `e.pageY+$("#popup").height()` (this is the sum of the clicked position's height and the popup's height). If the latter is less than the former, it means the popup can be shown. If `(e.pageY+$("#popup").height())>($(window).height()+window.pageYOffset)` it means the popup will overflow the window's bottom border, then its top offset should be changed to `e.pageY-$('#popup').height()`.

Here is the complete function:

```
$('.clickme').on('click', function(e) {    
    var h;
    if((e.pageY+$('#popup').height())<($(window).height()+window.pageYOffset)) h=e.pageY;
    else h=e.pageY-$('#popup').height();
           $('#popup').offset({ top: h, left:  e.pageX}).fadeIn(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your popup height is 100px, you can try this...

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
       var h = window.innerHeight;
        $('.clickme').on('click', function(e) { 
        alert(h + ", " + e.pageY);

        if( h - e.pageY < 125) {
            $('#popup').offset({ top: h-125, left:  e.pageX}).fadeIn();
        }
        else {
            $('#popup').offset({ top: e.pageY, left:  e.pageX}).fadeIn();
        }

        });
    });
```